# Cant run spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on an assignment with a team. And my team decided to use spring boot for the application. However for some reason whenever I run the application I get a different message on my terminal whereas my teammates have a different message on their terminal. Instead of "LiveReload server is running on port 35729" They get "tomcat initialized with port(s) 8081 (http)".

I am not sure what exactly to do since all of us are using the same project and I have built it as they told me to do so.

However it is still not working for me. Can anybody tell me how to fix it so I could get it to run. I have never used maven or spring boot before.

This is the message I am getting on my terminal

```
2020-06-13 23:05:35.538  INFO 34396 --- [  restartedMain] com.rest.WebApplication           : Starting WebApplication on DESKTOP-1M4A445 with PID 34396 (Directory\project\target\classes started by USER in Directory/project)


2020-06-13 23:05:35.543  INFO 34396 --- [  restartedMain] com.rest.WebApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default


2020-06-13 23:05:35.609  INFO 34396 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable


2020-06-13 23:05:36.520  INFO 34396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729


2020-06-13 23:05:36.550  INFO 34396 --- [  restartedMain] com.rest.WebApplication           : Started WebApplication in 1.452 seconds (JVM running for 2.035)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have `spring-boot-devtools` dependency in the classpath. Because of this you see `LiveReload server is running on port 35729` statement written to log.

From your logs, it seems tomcat is not started at all. Verify your properties files and make sure web environment is not turned off

- For spring-boot 1.x, look for `spring.main.web-environment=false` property
- For spring-boot 2.x, look for `spring.main.web-application-type=none` property